# Replacing a string on whole database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

*&amp* char has somehow got through different imports into the db on many different node attributes and relationship attributes. How do I replace all &amp; strings with regular & char?

I don't know all the possible property names that I can filter on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make this efficient, you can use CALL{} in transactions of X rows

The `:auto` prefix is needed if you want to run this query in the Neo4j browser

This line

```
WITH n, [x in keys(n) WHERE n[x] CONTAINS '&amp'] AS keys
```

is needed to avoid trying a `replace` function on a property that is not of `String` type, in which case Neo4j will throw an exception.

Full query

```
:auto MATCH (n)
CALL {
    WITH n
    WITH n, [x in keys(n) WHERE n[x] CONTAINS '&amp'] AS keys
    CALL apoc.create.setProperties(n, keys, [k in keys | replace(n[k], '&amp', '&')])
    YIELD node
    RETURN node
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 100 ROWS
RETURN count(*)
```

If you're using a Neo4j cluster, you will need to run this on the leader of the database with the bolt connection ( not using the `neo4j://` protocol.

Same query for the relationships now

```
:auto MATCH (n)-[r]->(x)
CALL {
    WITH r
    WITH r, [x in keys(r) WHERE r[x] CONTAINS '&amp'] AS keys
    CALL apoc.create.setRelProperties(r, keys, [k in keys | replace(r[k], '&amp', '&')])
    YIELD rel
    RETURN rel
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 100 ROWS
RETURN count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on this documentation:

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.setRelProperties/

For example, below will replace &amp with & in all properties in all nodes.

```
MATCH (p)
// collect keys (or properties) in node p and look for properties with &amp
WITH p, [k in keys(p) WHERE p[k] CONTAINS '&amp'] AS keys WHERE size(keys) > 0
// use apoc function to update the values in each prop key
CALL apoc.create.setProperties(p, keys, [k in keys | replace(p[k], '&amp', '&')])
YIELD node
RETURN node
```